# Asymmetric encryptions' computational complexity

Tags: encryption, public-key, complexity

I need to know the computational complexity of the public key encryption (e.g. Paillier), please.

(i.e.Paillier in his paper mentions that the computational complexity of most of public key encryptions is $O(n^3)$, but is not clear to me why)

Comment: Hint: start by establishing that (for arguments of $n$ bits) the cost of the [classic multiplication algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Long_multiplication) is $O(n^2)$ for arguments of $n$ bits; extend to $O(n^2)$ for $a\cdot b\bmod N$; then $O(n^3)$ for $x^d\bmod N$. There are [faster algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Fast_multiplication_algorithms_for_large_inputs), but they are not extremely useful in cryptography because $n$ is at most in the thousands (for RSA) or hundreds (for ECC).

Comment: @fgrieu I don't get how you conclude $O(n^3)$ from $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Using exponentiation by squaring, one needs $\mathcal O(n)$ underlying operations for a $n$-bit exponent. Hence, if the operation is computable in $\mathcal O(n^2)$ steps (which is mostly the case for practical systems, as mentioned above), the total cost is in $\mathcal O(n^3)$.

Comment: Many thanks. I found a detailed explanation: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6164/how-do-i-derive-the-time-complexity-of-encryption-and-decryption-based-on-modula